# Screen rotation issue 18.04 desktop version

Tags: 18.04, startup, ubuntu-studio, display-rotation

Because I've rotated my curved screen to portrait-style, I've changed the settings at All Settings/Display/Rotation (turn left). But every time my screen goes on standby, after I wake it up, it's turned to it's original position.

I've recently installed 18.04 on a desktop and I'm very new to this (very awesome) Linux thing, so I'm a serious n00b and can't figure it out... I've tried to find another thread with a working solution but no luck so far.

Is there a way to make the screen turn so the login screen is Portrait as well ? I've seen somebody say that it's only possible on login.

It would be so awesome if anyone could offer me a solution, I really want to fix it !

Greetings,

FG

Comment: Hi, are you using gdm or unity as display manager?

Answer (score 1):

Try to unload the module from RAM.

```
sudo modprobe -r lis3lv02d.
```

Or if you have an HP laptop you can remove the module hp_accel like this:-

```
sudo rmmod hp_accel
```